# Why debugging messages in stored procedure are not added when calling from other procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created stored procedure for debugging messages in mysql 8 :

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `TasksWithSearch`.`sp_debug`(
    IN in_label varchar(100),
    IN in_value varchar(1000),
    IN in_source varchar(100)
)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO data_debug(label, value, source) VALUES(in_label, in_value, in_source);

END
```

and when I call it from dbeaver as

```
call sp_debug( 'in_userId', 987, 'sp_taskComplete -3');
```

rows is added in debugging table. But When I try to call the same procedure from other procedure :

```
create procedure sp_taskComplete(IN in_taskId bigint unsigned,
                                                         IN in_completeSubtasks tinyint unsigned,
                                                         IN in_userId bigint unsigned,
                                                         OUT out_returnCode bigint unsigned)
BEGIN
    DECLARE taskCreatorId bigint unsigned;

    call sp_debug( 'in_taskId', 'in_taskId::', 'sp_taskComplete -1');

    SELECT creator_id INTO taskCreatorId from tasks WHERE id = in_taskId;
    IF (in_userId != taskCreatorId) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Only creator can complete task !';
        SET out_returnCode := -1;
    END IF;

    IF (in_completeSubtasks = 1) THEN
        call sp_debug( 'INSIDE in_completeSubtasks', -6, 'sp_taskComplete -6');
        CALL sp_checkCompleteSubtasks(@in_taskId := in_taskId, @in_completeSubtasks = in_completeSubtasks, @out_returnCode);
    END IF;

    UPDATE tasks SET status = 'D', completed_at = NOW() WHERE tasks.id = in_taskId;

    SET out_returnCode := in_taskId;
END;
```

No rows is added in debug table, while all the rest functionality is run ok.

What is wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add the call statement for sp_taskComplete

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (albeit I haven't imagined sp_checkCompleteSubtasks) https://dbfiddle.uk/nLitLcP7

Comment: Are you running this in a transaction? If the transaction is aborted, the INSERT will be rolled back.

Comment: a) sp_taskComplete is run from laravel with code like ` call sp_taskComplete(@in_taskId := 76, @in_completeSubtasks := 1,  @in_userId :=  12, @out_returnCode) ` under 1 transaction, which is completed with success. b) Are there similar tools in mysql 8 - I try to reinvent a wheel...